# SQL statement for how to return date and sales revenue

Tags: sql, oracle, cx-oracle

I am trying to run a SQL query to return my total sales of the day and date (yyyy-mm-dd format). I am running the code where filter_dailysales = (input date here) variable but it is not working.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(Orders_OrderTimeStamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd'), SUM(Orders_Price) 
  FROM Orders 
 WHERE TO_CHAR(Orders_OrderTimeStamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd') = '"+str(filter_dailysales)+"')
```

So I have table Orders with columns `Orders_ID`, `Orders_OrderTimeStamp`, `Orders_Price`

I have inputed code like this using cx_oracle on python

```
c.execute("insert into orders values ('9', 1.7, sysdate-31, 9, sysdate-31, '2', '1', '3')")
```

My desired result output would be first column: Date selected with an input variable, second column: The aggregated sum of orders_price. The results would just be one row.

Comment: Please tag with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: The key here is using the `GROUP BY` clause of SQL.

Comment: Hi sorry, just updated!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a group by to your query. Something like:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(Orders_OrderTimeStamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
,      SUM(Orders_Price) 
FROM Orders 
WHERE TO_CHAR(Orders_OrderTimeStamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd') = '"+str(filter_dailysales)+"')
GROUP BY TO_CHAR(Orders_OrderTimeStamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

Also, use bind variables instead of string substitution where possible. See:

https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/improve-sql-query-performance-by-using-bind-variables